# Why cant I z-index my comments and footer over my main content?

Tags: html, css, footer

My WordPress site doesn't seem to let me z-index my comment section over my main content. My goal is to have my .column-left be fixed in position, but it overlaps everything below it. This is what I currently have that you will see live at [jpshots.com](https://www.jpshots.com)

```
<div class="guts">
<div class="column-left"> copy </div>
<div class="colum-right"> gallery </div>
<div class="clear"></div>

.column-left{
float:left;
display: block;
width: 35%;
position: relative; 
height:100%;
z-index:1
}


#comments{
z-index:99999;
}

footer{
z-index:999999;
}
```

When I try to switch the position type of .column-left, it covers it up. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: YES! 
Adding `position:relative` to my footer and comment section did the trick. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z-index` does not work on `position:static` elements (which, mysteriously, is the default).

`z-index` only affects elements that are `position:relative`, `position:absolute` and `position:fixed`.

Try adding `position:relative` to your elements.

Note that `position:relative` operates pretty much identically to `position:static`, but it ***also*** works with absolute positioning and z-index.